# Launch specific external process in Scala

Tags: scala, command-line, process

I've been struggling to launch a specific external process in Scala. It works for most programs, but when I try

```
Array("gnome-terminal", "--working-directory", 
      "/mydir", "-x", "bash", "-c", "tmux attach")
```

it fails. I tried the same using Python's `subprocess.Popen` and it worked perfectly. Any suggestion?

My code is:

```
object Test {

    def main(args: Array[String]):Unit = {

        val source = Source.fromFile("file.txt")
        val lines = source.getLines

        lines.toList.map(raw => {
            val programAndOptions = raw.split('$')
            // here I get the Array mentioned above
            Process(programAndOptions) run
        })

        source.close
    }
}
```

#### *Update*

My `file.txt` is something like this:

```
evince$/path/to/my/pdf
evince$/path/to/other/pdf
nautilus$/path/to/my/working/directory
gnome-terminal$--working-directory$/mydir$-x$bash$-c$tmux attach
```

#### *Update2*

I ran the same code again to test and try some other things and it worked 'as is'.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: I don't actually get an error. The Terminal pop up and disappear quickly. If I leave the last part of (`"-c", "tmux attach"`), then it works, but that is not what I want.

Comment: I don't know what happened, but know I run the same code and it works...

Answer (score 0):

'Run' is non blocking so it execute the program and continue with the code, which is this case is source.close and exit.  Exiting the jvm probably kill the app.
Try using the '!' function instead of 'run' or do something like:

```
val p = Process(programAndOptions) run
p.exitValue
```

Comment: Using '!' blocks the execution, waiting for each program to execute and finish, which is not my goal here. I want to leave the programs running. My `file.txt` (see updated question) is something like this: `evince$/path/to/my/pdf` which works perfectly, except for the case I showed in my question. Thanks anyway :)